# Integration Resale Value Question

Tags: integration

During the first year of ownership the resale value of Abbey's 33000 dollar Car decreases to 27000 dollars. The drop in sale value is proportional to the resale value. Using calculus methods determine when the vehicle's resale value will drop below $10000.

I have attempted this question using integration techniques. I initially get the equation $\frac{dv}{dt} = -kv$.
I then integrate to get $ v = e^{-0.5k^2t}$.
However I think I am interpreting the question wrong since I am unable to get a reasonable answer when I substitute in my data.

Comment: You're expected to improve [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303736/integration-for-resale-value-question), not delete it and post it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

That's not the solution to the differential equation
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-kv.$$
This is solved via "separation of variables":
$$\int\frac{dv}{v}=\int(-k)\,dt$$
so
$$\ln v=-kt+\text{constant}$$
and
$$v=Ae^{-kt}$$
where $A$ is a constant.